# "Meanwhile" in present continuous sentence

Tags: commas, present-continuous

How to use "Meanwhile" in a present continuous sentence? 
For example, 
"Meanwhile, China laughing at all the superpower nations"
Is this sentence correct?

Comment: What part do _you_ think is incorrect? Hint: you said it was 'present continuous'.

Comment: @Rattler I know if it was "Laughed" instead of "Laughing", it would be correct but I wanna know whether laughing can be used in this sentence or not.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul What would I be looking for exactly?

Answer (score -1):

No, the sentence is not correct.

Yes, you can use *laughing*. But you have to make it a full sentence. I'd add the word *is*: "China *is* laughing . . . ."

You also need a period at the end to make it a full sentence: ". . . superpower nations**.**"

If you want the definition of *meanwhile*, you can look it up, as Decapitated Soul suggested.

Are you asking something else?

Comment: Once again this is a critique of the question, not an answer. Please stop critiquing questions in answers and editing questions to include critiques. You can edit questions to improve them, and if the OP is interested, they can review the edit history to see what has changed. Do not leave comments in the question pointing out their mistakes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/365358)